# Thymleaf javascript variable combining

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, template-engine

I'm using thymeleaf in my spring boot project. It's working well. Now I need to render one url in JavaScript as a string and need to concatenate with one JavaScript variable. I have tried the following code.

```
location.href = /*[[@{/signage/save}]]*/ '' + res.id
```

But the generated output is

```
location.href='/signage/save';
```

What I want is following

```
location.href = '/signage/save' + res.id;
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell Thymeleaf to uncomment certain code if the page is served dynamically using special comment syntax `/*[+...+]*/`. And inside this commented block, you can put expressions and they will be evaluated together with the whole block.

```
/*[+ location.href = [[@{/signage/save}]] + res.id +]*/
```

Will be rendered as

`location.href = '/signage/save' + res.id`

Answer (score 2):

After trying few methods got the solution, not exactly what I needed but it works for me. I just wrapped it using parenthesis (`(.....)`)

```
location.href = (/*[[@{/signage/save}]]*/ '') + res.id
```

and generated output is

```
location.href = ('/signage/save') + res.id;
```